# loading a header into an html file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem using the load function of JQuery. I am trying to load a header.html file into my index.html file and its not working

Lets say I have a file called header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fitness</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a file index.html. At the top of my body is `<div id="header"></div>` 
At the bottom of my body is

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#header").load("header.html");
  });
</script>
```

Why isnt my header loading into the div?

DISCLAMER: I know there are similar questions up already but I went through them and am still not able to get this to work.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Can you reproduce the issue as a code snippet so we can see it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Index.html is required to have an element id named header. If it does not have this element, load won't fire: http://api.jquery.com/load/

"If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the document does not contain an element with id="header" — the Ajax request will not be sent."

I think you want to wrap the content in header.html into a div with an id. Then pass that id into load to only take the contents of that div and place the contents into an element in index.html.

So inside header.html

```
<div id='header'> ...</div>
```

Inside Index.html:

```
<div id='dynamic-header'> ... </div>
```

Then jquery in index.html:

```
 $( "#dynamic-header" ).load( "header.html #header" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how your code base looks but because it's AJAX, I would say first off to ensure that you're running this code on a web server.

Secondly, since you're only loading the header from header.html, you can just specify that in your load function like this:

```
$("#header").load("header.html #firstHeader");
```

Assign the ID of #firstHeader to your header tag in header.html and this should work.

Comment: this is it, i was running it local, i just ran it on wamp and it works